# catkin_make --pkg astra_camera | /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenNI2Orbbec

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
aswin@aswin-laptop:~/camera$ catkin_make --pkg astra_camera
Base path: /home/aswin/camera
Source space: /home/aswin/camera/src
Build space: /home/aswin/camera/build
Devel space: /home/aswin/camera/devel
Install space: /home/aswin/camera/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/aswin/camera/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/aswin/camera/build/ros_astra_camera"
####
[ 11%] [ 11%] [ 11%] Built target astra_camera_gencfg
Built target astra_usb_reset
Performing update step for 'astra_openni2'
[ 11%] Built target _astra_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_GetSerial
[ 25%] [ 25%] [ 25%] Built target astra_camera_generate_messages_lisp
Built target astra_camera_generate_messages_py
Built target astra_camera_generate_messages_cpp
[ 25%] Built target astra_camera_generate_messages
Already on 'orbbec_ros'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/orbbec_ros'.
[ 29%] Performing configure step for 'astra_openni2'
no need to configure
[ 33%] Performing build step for 'astra_openni2'
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.
[ 37%] Performing install step for 'astra_openni2'
[ 40%] Completed 'astra_openni2'
[ 51%] Built target astra_openni2
Linking CXX shared library /home/aswin/camera/devel/lib/libastra_wrapper.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenNI2Orbbec
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/aswin/camera/devel/lib/libastra_wrapper.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ros_astra_camera/CMakeFiles/astra_wrapper.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250415/catkin_make---pkg-astra_camera-%7C-/usr/bin/ld:-cannot-find--lopenni2orbbec/) by [Aswin Sarang](https://answers.ros.org/users/27924/aswin-sarang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I answered this here - #q249988.

Cheers

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2017-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0